# Eliminar ramas locales mezcladas

Tags: git

Se que en git es posible eliminar ramas locales de la siguiente manera:

```
git branch -d "nombreRama"
```

La pregunta es ¿Existe un comando que pueda eliminar las ramas locales que ya fueron mezcladas con master?

Comment: Si la rama fue mezclada a master, el eliminar esa rama no afectara a master, el contenido seguirá ahí, solo ten en cuenta que no es lo mismo mezclar "nombreRama" con master, que mezclar master con "nombre de la rama", ya que dependiendo donde hagas el merge es en la rama que traerá los cambios

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert

Comment: `git branch --merged master` te da un  listado de las ramas que han sido ya mezcladas con master.

Comment: ¿Existe la forma de combinarlo con el git branch -d ?

Comment: Pues si estás en un linux puedes aprovecharte del shell, y poner ``git branch -d `git branch --merged master`  `` (un comando entre "backticks" en el shell es sustituido por lo que ese comando vuelque en la salida estándar). No obstante lo veo un poco peligroso. Yo haría antes sólo el `git branch --merged master` para asegurarte de que salen las ramas correctas antes de borrarlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes eliminar las ramas locales que ya han sido mezcladas con la master con el siguiente comando:

```
$ git branch --merged | egrep -v "\* master" | xargs git branch -d
```

De esta manera **se eliminaran todas las ramas que ya han sido mezcladas con la master**, sin eliminar sus commits, es decir, no se perderá nada del progreso que tengamos en el proyecto.